# REGEXP_REPLACE And NOT

Tags: google-bigquery

I wonder whether someone could help me please.

I'm trying to put together a REGEXP_REPLACE query which replaces data but only if it the string matches a certain condition.

This is the query I've come up with:

```
SELECT
  #select all fields excluding those under the hits record
  * EXCEPT (hits),
  #start array - this rebuilds the hit record
  ARRAY(
  SELECT
    #unnest the hit field, select each field excluding those under the page record
    AS STRUCT * EXCEPT (page),
    (
    SELECT
      #select all page fields excluding pageTitle
      AS STRUCT page.* EXCEPT (pagePath),
      #remove the query parameter from the pagePath fields
      REGEXP_REPLACE(page.pagePath, r'\/invitations\/([a-zA-Z0-9]{8})\/', '/invitations/([a-zA-Z0-9]{8})/redacted') AS pagePath) AS page
  WHERE
    AND NOT page.pagePath= (r'\/invitations\/[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}\/(ltd|limited|co|business')
  FROM
    UNNEST(hits) ) AS hits
FROM
  `Test.Test.ga_sessions_20190401`
```

The query doesn't work and the part that I'm struggling with is the WHERE NOT. I've tried using AND NOT REGEXP_MATCH in addition to the above, but I can't get this to work.

I just wonder whether someone could take a look at this please and offer some guidance how to solve this?

Many thanks and kind regards

Chris

Comment: Your `WHERE` has Immediately an `AND` after. You probably removed a condition.

Comment: And what's the problem exactly? Are you having problems się regex or with SQL query?

Comment: Hi @botchniaque. Thank you for coming back to me. I'm receiving a syntax error, but not sure why. Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just wonder whether someone could take a look at this please and offer some guidance on how to solve this?

Two issues in your code:

1. `FROM` was after the `WHERE`
2. Extra `AND` after the `WHERE`

This is the correct Sql:

```
SELECT
  #select all fields excluding those under the hits record
  * EXCEPT (hits),
  #start array - this rebuilds the hit record
  ARRAY(
  SELECT
    #unnest the hit field, select each field excluding those under the page record
    AS STRUCT * EXCEPT (page),
    (
    SELECT
      #select all page fields excluding pageTitle
      AS STRUCT page.* EXCEPT (pagePath),
      #remove the query parameter from the pagePath fields
      REGEXP_REPLACE(page.pagePath, r'\/invitations\/([a-zA-Z0-9]{8})\/', '/invitations/([a-zA-Z0-9]{8})/redacted') AS pagePath) AS page
  FROM
    UNNEST(hits) AS hits
  WHERE 
    NOT page.pagePath= (r'\/invitations\/[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}\/(ltd|limited|co|business')
    )
FROM
  `Test.Test.ga_sessions_20190401`
```

Comment: Hi @Tamir Klein. Thank you for replying. I've tried the solutions you kindly provided and the error message I receive is Error: Syntax error: Expected ")" but got keyword AND at [16:1]. Line 16 is the solution line you provided. Many thanks

Comment: I update my answer. As @botchniaque rightly commented you had a `WHERE AND` in your code and you should only have `WHERE`

Comment: Hi. Thank you for coming back to me with this. Unfortunately I'm still getting an error message, albeit different Error: Syntax error: Expected ")" but got keyword FROM at [19:3]. The FROM in question is the one above the UNNEST command. Many thanks and kind regards. Chris

Comment: Hi @Tamir Klein. That's great many thanks and kind regards. Chris

Comment: Happy to help :) Can you kindly vote up my answer as well since this is also important on SO as you probably know :)

Answer (score 1):

Below is for Bigquery Standard SQL. The benefit of below solution is that it does not change the structure of underlying table and just does replacement as needed

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * REPLACE(
  ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT * REPLACE(
      (SELECT
        AS STRUCT page.* REPLACE(
        REGEXP_REPLACE(page.pagePath, r'\/invitations\/([a-zA-Z0-9]{8})\/', '/invitations/([a-zA-Z0-9]{8})/redacted') AS pagePath)
      ) AS page)
    FROM UNNEST(hits) AS hits
    WHERE NOT page.pagePath= (r'\/invitations\/[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}\/(ltd|limited|co|business')
  ) AS hits)
FROM `Test.Test.ga_sessions_20190401`
```

Note using `SELECT * REPLACE` instead of `SELECT * EXCEPT`